# Mount Samba share without root access

Tags: linux, mount, samba, root, privileges

I have access to a Linux machine, but not root access.  I can access a Samba share through `smbclient`.  I'd like to be able to mount this share so I can access it from within Matlab.  Normally, if I had root access, this would be trivial.  But since I don't, I'm not sure how to proceed.

EDIT:

`smbmount` isn't installed on this machine.  `mount.cifs` is installed, which I think I read is a replacement for `smbmount`?  However, when I try it, it says I need to run it sudo.

Does `smbmount` (or `mount.cifs`) need to be suid in order for a non-root user to mount a Samba share?

Comment: I've never tried this and I'm not near a linux machine, but you could try mounting it to a folder in your home directory. `mkdir ~/mnt` and then `mount //SERVED/SAMBASHARE ~/mnt` might work?

Answer (score 4):

Try gvfs-mount, like this:

```
gvfs-mount smb://user:pass@server/storage
```

This is what Nautilus uses to mount a remote share without root access.

From within Nautilus, you can enter `smb://user:pass@server/storage` at the location bar. I believe this can help you find the share from within Matlab.

Example:

```
gvfs-mount smb://alexsmith:mypassword@everest/myshare
```

Please note the fields `user` and `pass` are optional, so you could use:

```
gvfs-mount smb://everest/myshare
```